# Bootstrap table look different on Firefox after apply DataTable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have following display on the Firefox of the table which I don't know why it's displaying like that........

[image]

As I want something like following output in Firefox as well which is displaying in chrome browser

[image]

As Chrome output is so perfect and look at the Firefox(First image) look like all the columns width are wrong..here....

I have applied dataTable.js and when I remove it my Firefox output like following which is I want but with the dataTable.js on it....

[image]

So can anyone help me and at the moment I have not included my html side code because there is nothing special I have applied so can anyone look at this issue and if anyone really wants my html code then please let me know guys.

I don't want to spend whole day of mine to figure out only this as may be someone expert out there.....as I surf net as well for this issue but couldn't figure it out....
Thank you guys and let me know if need anything....

html code:

```
<div class="portlet-body">
                                                <div class="table-scrollable" style="padding:20px !important;">
                                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-advance table-hover dataTablemy">
                                                    <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <th class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
                                                                Type
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th class="col-sm-8">
                                                                Details
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th class="hidden-xs" style="background-color: white !important;">
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th class="hidden-xs" style="background-color: white !important;">
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th class="hidden-xs" style="background-color: white !important;">
                                                            </th>

                                                    </tr>   
                                                    </thead>    
                                                    <tbody>

                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>Job Completed</td>
                                                            <td>Job Ref: 306789 for ABC Ltd. completed by contractor. Duration: 2.5 days. Cost: $1452.78</td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <a data-toggle="modal" href="" onclick=""><i class=" fa-2x icon-info"></i></a>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <a data-toggle="modal" href="" onclick=""><i class=" fa-2x icon-speech"></i></a>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <a href="#" class="tooltips" onclick=""  data-placement="top" data-original-title="dismiss"><i class=" fa-2x icon-close"></i></a>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
```

Comment: html and css code would be helpful please

Comment: I looks exactly the same to me, using dataTables 1.10.9, bootstrap 3.3.5 - and dataTables.bootstrap.* ...Are you sure this is not a cache problem???

Comment: Yes I am sure it's not the cache so any idea on this please help...thanks and sorry for late reply as weekend and busy on other projects.